# di xml for corresponding config magento 2 : dispatch() error

Tags: magento2

In my Magento 2 front page, if i click on the categories/subcategories menu, i get

Call to a member function dispatch() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php on line 644.

**My system.log** says:

Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

I am actually migrating my 1x magento to 2x.

Could you please help with the corresponding code for di.xml under etc.

My **updated di.xml** is as

```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
                    <!--Overrride for Block catalog rewrite product list toolbar -->
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct" />
<preference for="ToolbarModel" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\SearchList\Toolbar" />    <!--ToolbarModel: alias for Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar -->
                    <!--Override for Block catalog Search layer -->
<preference for="\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogSearch\Layer" />

<!-- Override model: Catalog Resource-->
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\Resource\Product\Collection" />
```

If i search for products by clicking category menu, i get the above mentioned error?
Is it cause of my incomplete di xml file?

Comment: Looks like the problem in you Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct or Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Catalog\Product\SearchList\Toolbar class constructor. Can you add it to question?

Comment: added ListProduct, Toolbar and dixml

Comment: Kandy , any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can find this problem by self if you try to run Magento static and integrity test.**

Problem in  \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar constructor. You do not pass all parameters to the parent class.

Replace

```
public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper
    //\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    //array $data=[]
) {
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
    //parent::__construct($context,$data);

}
```

on

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    ToolbarModel $toolbarModel,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    ProductList $productListHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,

    array $data
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $catalogSession,
        $catalogConfig,
        $toolbarModel,
        $urlEncoder,
        $productListHelper,
        $postDataHelper,
        $data
    );
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
}
```

(see full class name in parrent class)

Comment: Its still showing the same error after replacing

Comment: I have updated Toolbar with the constructors still has dispacth() error

Comment: Verify other blocks